# Get Form Input value to jQuery AJAX call URL variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Trying to get the HTML Input Form value to a jQuery AJAX call's URL as `amt` in `url: "http://localhost:8080/orderNo?amount="  + amt,`.  I'm able to get the input value to log to the console by calling getAmtValue() but seem to be unable to get the amt value outside.  What am I doing wrong here please? Scoping issue?

```
<body>

 <form class="form-inline" onsubmit = " return getAmtValue()">

      Find orders by amount :<br>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control inputArea" id="getAmt" placeholder="Enter Amount">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>
    </form>



</body>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var amt = "";




    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/orderNo?amount="  + amt ,

        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
         },
         dataType : "json",
         success : function(data) {
            let text = "";
            for (let x in data) {

                 $('.order_amt').append("<br>" + data[x].amt + "<br>");
                 $('.order_number').append("<br>" + data[x].order_no + "<br>");
                 $('.order_date').append("<br>" + data[x].date + "<br>"):
                 }


            }


    });//End AJAX





});//End $(document).ready(function()) 

function getAmtValue(){
      amt = document.getElementById("getamt").value;

      console.log("Value from input : " + amt);

      return false;
     };

</script>
```

Update:

Per McB & Nawed Khan, now working like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    let amt = "";

});//End $(document).ready(function()) 

function getAmtValue(){
      amt = document.getElementById("getamt").value;

      console.log("Value from input : " + amt);

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/orderNo?amount="  + amt ,

        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
         },
         dataType : "json",
         success : function(data) {
            let text = "";
            for (let x in data) {

                 $('.order_amt').append("<br>" + data[x].amt + "<br>");
                 $('.order_number').append("<br>" + data[x].order_no + "<br>");
                 $('.order_date').append("<br>" + data[x].date + "<br>"):
                 }


            }


    });//End AJAX

      return false;
    };
```

Comment: The whole order is just messed up. On page load, after document is ready you are setting amt="" and sending it to ajax. Then only when someone hits the submit button you are reading the value into amt but not sending it. Move the whole ajax inside getAmtValue() before return false;

Comment: Can you include you getAmtValue() function? Right now your Ajax is going to use "" as the amt value because that's what you set it to right before the code. Could change to document.getElementById('getAmt').value, use that directly in your ajax request.

Comment: @McB Hi - if you mean include the code, `getAmtValue()` function is at the bottom of the `<script>` - thanks

Comment: Missed that it scrolled down. Then yes, as Nawed Khan said, move everything from $.ajax to //End Ajax into getAmtValue, right below where you set set the amt variable (also, `let amt=...`, or `const amt=...` is probably better)

Comment: @McB - Could you please show an example in code? Seems to not want to work the way I rearranged the code - thanks.

Comment: I can't test much because it's a local server and all, but looking at your code, it's case sensitive, so getElementById('getAmt') not 'getamt'. Then move all of your Ajax code directly below that line (literally the next line down).

Comment: @McB - thanks - per you and Nawed Khan, I got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the ajax call inside the function that is called on form submit. So the whole javascript will look like this:

```
<script>
function getAmtValue(){
   var amt = document.getElementById("getAmt").value;
   console.log("Value from input : " + amt);

   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://localhost:8080/orderNo?amount="  + amt ,

     xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
     },
     dataType : "json",
     success : function(data) {
        let text = "";
        for (let x in data) {           
          $('.order_amt').append("<br>" + data[x].amt + "<br>");
          $('.order_number').append("<br>" + data[x].order_no + "<br>");
          $('.order_date').append("<br>" + data[x].date + "<br>"):
        }
     }
   });//End AJAX

   return false;
};
</script>
```